# Running tests with Selenium Webdriver and Testng, Assertion is failing but testng is not showing the test as failed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm running my tests with Selenium Webdriver and Testng. Im using asserts in my tests. The problem I'm facing is that even when the assertion is failing, testng is not showing the test as failed.
[TestNG Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbUhV.jpg)

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Please edit this question and include the full error stack. Also include what you've tried and did not work.

Comment: CydrickT,
If you click on TestNG Console link in the question, you will see the error stack. I purposefully failed this test but at the end its not showing the test as failed.

Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Comment: Are you using a try-catch block? If so, then you need to put a fail statement in catch block.

Comment: AGill,
I have tried that also.Its not working. Somehow I'm getting a passed status. Right now I'm using testng asserts.